# Method overloading or something more elegant?

Tags: c#, overloading, named-parameters

I am writting some code in C# and I noticed scenario like below. I wonder how can I make this more elegant and easy to maintain.

If I have following scenario with overloads

```
public void DoSmtg(string a) { DoSmtg(a, 0, 0f); }
public void DoSmtg(string a, int x) { DoSmtg(a, x, 0f); } 
public void DoSmtg(string a, int x, double d) { // method logic }
```

say now I need to add another bool parameter.  I would have to modify this to

```
public void DoSmtg(string a) { DoSmtg(a, 0, 0f, false); }
public void DoSmtg(string a, int x) { DoSmtg(a, x, 0f, false); } 
public void DoSmtg(string a, int x, double d, bool doIt) { // method logic }
```

This is a very simple example.  It is possible to have say 10 more versions of DoSmtg() method.  Clearly, this code smells.  While overloading is quite valid, it obviously makes it hard to maintain this code since:

1. there are many methods to be written
2. it is not obvious which method is called until careful investigation (especially if method has more parameters)
3. method gets poluted by growing parameter list
4. the new parameter added requires changes at many places (think about the methods above called from many different locations)

What would be an elegant, simple and good way to avoid something like this?

Comment: If those parameters are in any way related, consider packing them up into a class and making `.DoSmtg` a method of that class.

Comment: What @JeroenMostert said; I was just typing the same comment. :) Or even if `DoSmtg` is not a member of the class, maybe the formals are related configuration data; then it might be worthwhile to make an abstraction specifically for this concept and pass it to `DoSmtg`. (Of course, that just pushes the problem off a level; now you have the same problem for constructors of the abstraction.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: What is your objective standard for "elegant"? Stack Overflow does not handle "primarily opinion-based questions".

Comment: This question clearly belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding all the parameters on one function, using default values and name the parameters when you call the function:

```
public void DoSmtg(string a, int x=0, double d=0f, bool doIt=false) { 
    // method logic 
}
```

When calling the function, you would then do:

```
DoSmtg("yo!")
DoSmtg("yo!", d:0.59, doIt:true)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this breaks existing compiled code that depends on the other overloads.

Comment: Good point. There are also breaks possible when recompiling code. An example: in the original code, `Action<string> a = DoSmtg;` is legal; in the new code it is not and this would become an error.

Comment: Visual Studio has great refactoring support ;)

Comment: Nice use of named arguments here.

Comment: @KyleFalconer  I think I like this idea.  I dont have problems with modifying existing 100+ calls to my overloads.  At least I will remove the 10+ overloads and make them a single method.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap all the parameters up in a POCO:

```
public class SomethingParameters
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public double D { get; set; }
    public bool DoIt { get; set; }
}
```

Then the method signature becomes:

```
public void DoSmtg(SomethingParameters parameters) { // method logic }
```

I like this pattern because it's easy to extend in the future. If you need to add five more parameters, or optional parameters, no problem!

You can call it like:

```
var parameters = new SomethingParameters()
{
    A = "foobar",
    X = 123,
    D = 0.123,
    DoIt = false
}

DoSmtg(parameters);
```

If you have a lot of code calling the old method signature that you don't want to break, you could keep your existing overloads but have them call the new one:

```
public void DoSmtg(string a, int x, double d, bool doIt)
    => DoSmtg(new SomethingParameters()
              {
                  A = a,
                  X = x,
                  D = d,
                  DoIt = doIt
              });
```

Comment: I like your idea but I am not sure how to invoke the method.  I have to instantiate the instance of the class on each call and set its parameters right?  Something like DoSmtg(new SomethingParameters(A, X, D, DoIt));.  I like this but it has problem with public parameters and it seem to be still same issue.  Although more elegant.

Comment: @dbnex14 You can instantiate the class earlier, too. Il not sure what you mean by "it has a problem with public parameters"?

Comment: @dbnex14 you can instantiate the instance of the class like new SomethingParameters { A = valueA, D = valueD }. You don't need to do overloads of SomethingParameters .ctor

Comment: @dbnex14 Yan is correct. You can initialize the class using `{}` instead of the constructor, which gives you more flexibility for optional parameters (and parameter order). Edited my answer to include some more examples.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the option of using a separate class for parameters. But perhaps, as you said, you're already calling the method in multiple places and don't want to modify it.
In that case you can add an optional parameter:

```
public void DoSmtg(string a, int x, double d, bool doIt = false)
```

Nothing has to change anywhere else except that you can supply the parameter if you choose to.

If you find yourself doing this I'd still write the extra overload using a class anyway and start using that. Optional parameters can start to get messy too if there are too many of them.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHannen but I already have optional parameters.  The issue remains though.  If I am to add a new parameter, I will need to do lots of modifications.

Comment: If you only add an optional parameter than the only changes are to the methods themselves and the to the callers that will pass the optional parameter.